# finding the radius of the circle given a coordinate

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

find the radius of the circle with center at (-1,2) if a chord of length 10 is bisected at (4,-3).(this is exactly what our professor given to us)

im thinking of using the distance formula which is

d=√(x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2

but our topic is about division of line segment but i think i cant use that because the problem is about finding the length of radius of a circle
[link of the formula](http://techiemathteacher.com/2013/12/05/division-of-line-segment/)

and ive tried to graph it, but i dont know if it is correct.

[my graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaTas.png)

this is according on my understanding

Comment: See  https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Perpendicular_Bisector_of_Chord_Passes_Through_Center

Comment: @labbhattacharjee sorry i didn't understand the link :(

Comment: I am surprised that the problem has a unique solution. Bisection of a chord seems to be a rather strong property of a given line through a circle.

Answer (score 2):

As the perpendicular bisector of any chord of any given circle must pass through the center O$(-1,2)$ of that circle.

If $P(4,-3)$ is midpoint of the chord and $R$ is one of the extreme points,

$OR^2=OP^2+PR^2, PR=5$ unit

Answer (score 1):

Let the center be O. It says the chord of length 10 is bisected at (4,-3). Let the chord be AB and its mid point be D which is (4,-3).
Now we know, the perpendicular from center to a chord bisects it, so we have two right angular triangles, ∆OAD and ∆OBD where OA will be radius, r.
You can calculate OD by using the distance formula. And we know that OD bisects AB so AD = DB = 10.2 =5.
So now you simply have to use pythagoras theoram on, say OAD, where OA = r, AD = 5, and OD = 5√2 (you can calculate using distance formula as you have the coordinates of both O and D).
So, OA^2 = OD^2 + AD^2.
You should get radius as 5√3.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's much better.